# Too many image imports in React Native cause white screen

Tags: reactjs, image, import, native

Im creating an app in which in each round 3 out of 40 images ought to be selected and shown on the screen. I do that by importing all of the images, placing them in an array and then choosing from array randomly. This works with 20 images, but as soon as I try to import all of them I get this white screen at the app launch and it doesn't go away. Images are not huge, all of them are under 500kB. 
I also tried placing them in another file 'images.js' and then pulling from that file, but it didn't work. 
Any solutions?

Comment: Can you share some code how do you import all these images?

Comment: `const one36 = require('../../../img/36/01.jpg');` I do it like that 40 times :/

Comment: Why not load images on demand? 
For example : 

const image = require('../../../img/'+index1+'/'+index2+'.jpg');

where index 1 and 2 are respective numbers of the image you need?

Comment: I've read somewhere that that is not a recommended way of doing it, but if no one else offers a solution I will probably rehaul my code to fit that. Thanks.